# Generating k-mers from a list of monomers in python using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to build a function that returns or yields a list of k-mers from a list of letters (DNA-bases). K would represent the length (or the order) of the k-mers.

I have made this function which prints the desired result into the screen. The point is that I cannot get the function return those values.

```
def function(k,y=''):
    letters=['A','C','T','G']
    if k==0:
        print(y)
    else:
        for m in letters:
            kmer=m+y
            function(k-1,kmer)
```

I have though in returning a list or yielding the k-mers but none of the options work. When I change the print for yield or return the function returns None.

It may be a concept error, I am just understanding recursive functions as I come from a biological background.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `yield from` in your recursive call (needs Python 3.3+):

```
def function(k, y=''):
    if k==0:
        yield y
    else:
        for m in ['A','C','T','G']:
            yield from function(k-1, m+y)
```

Testing:

```
>>> [x for x in function(2)]
['AA', 'CA', 'TA', 'GA', 'AC', 'CC', 'TC', 'GC', 'AT', 'CT', 'TT', 'GT', 'AG', 'CG', 'TG', 'GG']
```

Comment: perfect! It also works for me! I'll read a bit more about that "yield from" to get a better understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, done!   ;-) Although I use python >3.3 I have modified it a bit to fit the solution also with python <3.3. just change "yield from" with for "item in get_kmers(k-1,kmer): yield item"

Comment: You could replace `yield from function(k-1, m+y)` with `for res in function(k-1, m+y): yield res` for example.

Answer (score 0):

People already showed how to use yield, I will show how to return all the kmers together (might be undesirable if k is too high and there will be too many of them)

```
def giveKmers(k):
    def function(k, y=''):
        letters = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']
        if k:
            for m in letters:
                function(k - 1, m + y)
        else:
            arr.append(y)

    arr = []
    function(k)
    return arr


print giveKmers(2)
```